# JSONArray gets over-written

Tags: java, json, jqgrid

I use [simple-json](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

I am trying to create JSON Object for jqgrid. The data gets added but properly but second record gets overwritten.

```
 ArrayList resList = connect.statement_query(sql, para);

            jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            jsonObject.put("total", resList.size()/para.length);
            jsonObject.put("page", 1);
            jsonObject.put("records", resList.size()/para.length);

            JSONArray cellArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONArray cell = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject cellObj = new JSONObject();

            for (int i = 0; i < resList.size(); i += para.length) {
                cellObj.put("id", resList.get(i));

                JSONArray temp=new JSONArray();
                temp.add(resList.get(i));
                temp.add(resList.get(i + 1));
                temp.add(resList.get(i + 2));
                temp.add(resList.get(i + 3));
                temp.add(resList.get(i + 4));

                cell=temp;
                cellObj.put("cell", cell);
                System.out.println("Cell Obj: "+cellObj.toJSONString());
                cellArray.add(cellObj);
                System.out.println("Cell Array: "+cellArray.toJSONString());
                //cellObj.clear();
                temp.clear();
            }
            System.out.println("Cell Array-Out: "+cellArray);
            jsonObject.put("rows", cellArray);
```

The result comes out as:

```
Cell Obj: {"id":"1000","cell":["1000","BE6K","vshekhar","2014-06-02","N\/A"]}
Cell Array: [{"id":"1000","cell":["1000","BE6K","vshekhar","2014-06-02","N\/A"]}]
Cell Obj: {"id":"1001","cell":["1001","BOA","maahamad","2013-05-01","N\/A"]}
Cell Array: [{"id":"1001","cell":["1001","BOA","maahamad","2013-05-01","N\/A"]},{"id":"1001","cell":["1001","BOA","maahamad","2013-05-01","N\/A"]}]
Cell Array-Out: [{"id":"1001","cell":[]},{"id":"1001","cell":[]}]
```

1. Why is Cell Array getting overwritten on second record and why does it gets blank out side the loop? How to overcome it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) For object getting over written -

You need to reintialize cellObj in for loop.

for (int i = 0; i < resList.size(); i += para.length) {
    
cellObj = new JSONObject();

2) For Cell getting blank out -

You are clearing temp by 'temp.clear();' Cell object is referencing temp, and temp is cleared out, that is the reason you are getting blank data.

you can remove temp.clear() code.

Comment: that makes it worse. 

`Cell Obj: {"id":"1000","cell":["1000","BE6K","vshekhar","2014-06-02","N\/A"]}
Cell Array: [{"id":"1000","cell":["1000","BE6K","vshekhar","2014-06-02","N\/A"]}]
Cell Obj: {"id":"1001","cell":["1001","BOA","maahamad","2013-05-01","N\/A"]}
Cell Array: [{"id":"1000","cell":[]},{"id":"1001","cell":["1001","BOA","maahamad","2013-05-01","N\/A"]}]
Cell Array-Out: [{"id":"1000","cell":[]},{"id":"1001","cell":[]}]`

Comment: tried that. If I dont clear it. It still overwrites.

Comment: thanks for the help. Seems the issue was with JAR. Updated the version and it is working fine. temp.clear() works now. Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried both? reinitialize cellObj and don't clear temp? Because I tried the same code and its working fine. Please recheck.